# ifelse behaviour in R

Tags: r, if-statement

First of all I declare that I checked all the related question on `ifelse`, but without any success.
I am trying to use `ifelse` to add a factor (mating period) in wildlife species according to the months. An example of the DB  is below:

```
> DB <- data.frame(ID = 1:6, Month = 1:12)
colnames(DB) <- c("ID","Month")
```

What I have tried is:

```
Period<-with(DB,ifelse(Month==c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),"M","R")))
```

but the result doesn't match the condition:

```
(Period)[1] "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "R" "R"
```

and there is also a warning:

```
Warning message:
In Month == c(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10) :
longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`
```

Surprisingly, when I launch the script on the real DB two things happen:

- In the new column Period some M appears
- No warning comes out

I am now really confused on how `ifelse` works. I hope someone could clarify how this function works and how properly type the script to obtain the correct result.

Comment: You might want to accept some answers to your questions, give your responders some extra reputation and tidy the place up a bit :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your comparison is of the wrong form. `ifelse` goes through one element at a time making the comparison whereas `Month == 2:10` will pairwise compare the elements and return a vector indicating whether each pairwise comparison is true or false.

You want to use `%in%` which returns true or false depending on whether an element is in a vector:

```
Period<-with(DB,ifelse(Month %in% 2:10,"M","R")))
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `%in%`as in:

```
Period<-with(DB,ifelse(Month %in% c(2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10),"M","R"))
Period
 [1] "R" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "M" "R" "R"
```

Comment: Hi Jack,thank you so much for the explanation: it is very useful because I do not find any replies on the use of ifelse that report the use of %in%!!!Really helpful and of course the script works greatly! Hi Jilber of course even your script works very well, I really appreciate the support of the community: the world is not so bad!!!Once again, many many thanks!!!