# R: Unexpected behaviour in ifelse

Tags: r, if-statement

I would like to understand why this (to me) unexpected behaviour is happening, because I do not understand the logic behind. This is a perfectly reproducible example.

Let's start with two different vectors:

```
comp1 <- c(90,2,113,123,99,203,1,137,1,140,44)
action <- c(2,1,1)
```

Now, I want to do a simple `ifelse` check and if it is false, I want to delete the first row, and if I simply do this, it works fine:

```
action <- action[2:length(action)]

> action
[1] 1 1
```

This is exactly right and this is what I want. Now, if I use the `ifelse` function with a false boolean like this:

```
action <- ifelse(any(49==comp1), 2, action[2:length(action)])
```

I am telling it if `TRUE` to put put a `2` in `action` and if `FALSE` to do the previous operation `action[2:length(action)]`. Now, as you can see the default condition in this case is `FALSE`, as there is no 49 in the `comp1` vector from above, and I would be expecting, as before, `1 1` vector as a result. However, the result is unexpected:

```
> action
[1] 1
```

Following other threads such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14399591/ifelse-behaviour-in-r) I also tried using `%in%` with the same outcome.

```
> action <- ifelse(49 %in% comp1, 2, action[2:length(action)])
> action
[1] 1
```

Does anybody have any idea why this is happening?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `if/else` instead of `ifelse` as `ifelse` requires all arguments to be of same `length`.  The first argument 'test' is of length 1, 'yes' 1 whereas 'no' is of different length.  According to `?ifelse`

> If yes or no are too short, their elements are recycled. yes will be evaluated if and only if any element of test is true, and analogously for no.

```
if(49 %in% comp1) 2 else action[2:length(action)]
[1] 1 1
```

Comment: I understand, I didn't know about this and it makes perfect sense with your explanation. Thank you very much @akrun